# Blake2B as a KDF

Tags: key-derivation, blake2

How would one go about using vanilla keyed Blake2B as a KDF with high-entropy inputs. Assume I don't have access to more specialized algorithms such blake2XB, HKDF, etc.

- Salt - high entropy per-encryption salt (32 bytes)
- IKM - high entropy static input keying material (32 bytes)
- Info - a personalization string for the key being derived

Would a construction such as Blake2B(input: $(\text{Salt} \parallel \text{Info})$, key: $\text{IKM}$) be sound?

Taking into account that Blake2 is not prone to length extension attacks, how does the aforementioned construction compare to Blake2B(input: $(\text{Salt} \parallel \text{Info} \parallel \text{IKM})$)?

Comment: I think of blake2b as a function of type $\{0,1\}^* -> \{0,1\}^{256}$. Given that, it isn't clear what you mean by `Blake2B(input: (Salt || Info), key: IKM)` - how is the key input into blake2b?  Also, NIST has a perfectly fine KDF construction using hash and counter (typically SHA512) which could readily be used with any secure hash algorithm.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I mean there are a myriad of Blake implementations; Blake, Blake2, Blake2B, Blake2S, Blake2XB, Blake2XS, Blake2BP, Blake2SP. Within most implementations of Blake2B I find some that accept a key as input.  Some offer salts and personalization strings... some variable-length outputs (which differs from simple truncation). Frankly. it's a bit overwhelming. Anyway, my question refers to Blake2B implementations that accept a key parameter (or no params other than the input). Regarding what NIST offers - my question is not regarding alternative primitives.

Comment: NISTs method is a way to use a hash, not an alternate primitive.

Comment: "Assume I don't have access to more specialized algorithms such blake2XB, HKDF, etc.". My question is regarding Blake2B. If I specifically pre-empt dismissive suggestions to go with NIST protocols,  could you do me the courtesy of not suggesting them?

Comment: So the actually secret value that you want to derive the key from is this IKM and the Salt and Info are just for diversification?

Comment: @Elias  yes - the concept/terminology is borrowed from [HKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, what you want is possible with plain Blake2b - if your implementation supports the [full specification (PDF)](https://blake2.net/blake2.pdf) (which is marked as optional by [RFC 7693](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7693#section-2.5)).

If this is the case, you'd do the following mappings:

- Feed the `info` data into the `personalization` -part of the parameter block.
- Feed the `salt` data into the `salt` -part of the parameter block.
- Feed the `IKM` data into the key-input of the Blake2b.

Alternatively you can also just feed the `info` into the main hashing input.

Note thought that key is limited to a size of 64 bytes (the maximum for Blake2b). So if you expect your `IKM` to be regularly larger than that, it might make sense to mandate straight pre-hashing of your `IKM` so it fits in.

It gets more interesting if your `salt` and `info` exceeed 16 bytes in size (which is the maximum defined for Blake2b) or if your Blake2 implementation only supports the key-input.

In this case what you want is to use a proper [pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function), so that a salt of `0xDEADBEEF` won't produce the same result as a salt of `0xDEAD` and a personalization of `0xBEEF`. Now the simplest such pairing function would be to also include the lengths of the inputs. So you would hash `info_length || salt_length || info || salt` where the lengths are 32- or 64-bit integers (constant-sized!). Alternatively you could fix a maximal length for either input and then append fill up the remaining space with `0xFF(0x00)*`.

Answer (score 4):

Shortening the definition of HKDF (for sufficiently short output) it is just:

`HMAC(HMAC(XTS, SKM), CTXinfo || 0)`

(format: `HMAC(key, msg)`)

Since this is barely more complicated than your example of

`Blake2B(input: (Salt || Info), key: IKM)`

I would recommend doing that instead. I know you explicitly stated you don't have access to HKDF but I don't see the big difference here.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `HMAC(HMAC(XTS, SKM), CTXinfo || 1)` (instead of `0`) for the first output block?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PBKDF2, using Blake2b as the hash function. One of the parameters to PBKDF2 *is* the hash function you want to use:

```
PBKDF2(PRF, Password, Salt, Iterations, DesiredBytes)
```

So it can be:

- PBKDF2<sub>sha1</sub>(Password, Salt, Iterations, DesiredBytes)
- PBKDF2<sub>sha2-256</sub>(Password, Salt, Iterations, DesiredBytes)
- PBKDF2<sub>sha3</sub>(Password, Salt, Iterations, DesiredBytes)
- PBKDF2<sub>blake2b</sub>(Password, Salt, Iterations, DesiredBytes)

Blake2b algorithm has the ability itself to generate keys up to 512 bytes long.

- but if you need an alternative
- or someone is demanding the use of PBKDF2
- or you need a key that is longer than 512-bits

then using a password-based key-derivation function to derive a key from a password also works.

It's also useful information to know, as many people only think of:

- PBKDF2_sha1
- PBKDF2_sha256

and don't realize that you can substitute any hash function you like.

And in the end, spreading more information to man-kind is what stackexchange is about.

Comment: I don't think there is a scenario where I'd go with this combination. For password hashing there are better choices than PBKDF2 (e.g. bcrypt, scrypt, argon2, or even a plain iterated hash). For key based hashing, HKDF is much simpler and more flexible than PBKDF2.

Comment: bcrypt isn't a key-derivation function; it's a password hashing algorithm. In this case we're not using a KDF to add computational time, we're only using it to convert an arbitrary length password into a specific number of bits for an encryption key. E.g. `correct horse battery staple` ==> 56-bit DES key, `hunter2 all i see is asterisks` ==> 192-bit AES key. The asker noted that we assume the incoming password already is high-entropy. script and argon2 can also be used as key-derivation functions (in addition to people using them as password hashing algorithms).