# Simplistic double ratchet implementation

Tags: encryption, libsodium

Would something like this be a reasonable way to implement the double ratchet with `libsodium`? The sodium port that I'm using is quite limited and does not offer a kdf.

[Here](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/advanced/scalar_multiplication) is a link to the libsodium documentation page regarding the scalar multiplication.

What `crypto_scalarmult_base / crypto_scalarmult` does is: "compute a shared secret given a user's secret key and another user's public key".

```
// random key shared between parties during the initial handshake
const preKey = "yez6GrvuVl3zihPwHf9wiXUv93CSkXHBQhPs6e0YLxg="

// compute the first chain key based on the shared pre key
const chain1 = sodium.crypto_scalarmult_base(preKey)

// compute the actual message key, since chain has just started, 
// use the pre key as the "public key" and chain1 key as 
// the "secret key" for the multiplication
const key1 = sodium.crypto_scalarmult(chain1, preKey)

const cipher1 = encrypt_message(key1)
      
// compute the next chain2 key based on the previous chain1 key
const chain2 = sodium.crypto_scalarmult_base(chain1)

// compute the next message key based on the chain2 key, 
// used as the "secret key" and the chain1 key used as 
// the "public key" for the multiplication
const key2 = sodium.crypto_scalarmult(chain2, chain1)

const cipher2 = encrypt_message(key2)
      
const chain3 = sodium.crypto_scalarmult_base(chain2)
const key3 = sodium.crypto_scalarmult(chain3, chain2)

const cipher3 = encrypt_message(key3)

// and so on ....
```

From what I understand, scalarmult is not backtrackable and breaking `key2` would not allow you to calculate `key1` nor `key3`.

So my question is - is an implementation like this reasonable or a total disaster?

Comment: @fgrieu Thank you for your comment, I've tried to clarify the code a bit.

Comment: The question is expressed with code, and it would be best to at least sum up what `sodium.crypto_scalarmult` performs, both with one and two arguments. As an alternative, link to a relevant documentation.

Comment: `_base` computes a public key from a private key. `scalarmult` also allows several different public keys to compute the same shared secret, which can be a vulnerability in some protocols. And you shouldn't use a shared secret as a key directly. You should at least hash the shared secret concatenated with both public keys. About all I can say on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly encourage you to carefully read the entire [Point*scalar multiplication](https://doc.libsodium.org/advanced/scalar_multiplication) page and Signal's Double Ratchet [documentation](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/doubleratchet/). You can also read about the Double Ratchet and Signal protocol in the book Real-World Cryptography.

Make sure you understand what the libsodium functions do, how the Double Ratchet algorithm works, and why the algorithm was designed that way.

> So my question is - is an implementation like this reasonable or a
> total disaster?

It's unclear what the `preKey` is, but a key exchange involves exchanging two public keys, not a single key. If you exchange a single key, there's no need to use asymmetric cryptography like this at all. The tricky part is keeping that single key secure, which is why public keys (non-secrets) are normally exchanged.

`crypto_scalarmult_base()` computes a public key from the private key, not a shared secret.

`crypto_scalarmult()` computes a shared secret for a private key and someone else's public key. It looks like it's being used to compute a shared secret from what you believe to be another shared secret; I'm not entirely sure. There should be more than one key exchange going on.

You shouldn't use shared secrets directly because they're not uniformly random. They're meant to be passed through a KDF.

Also, for a given public key with X25519, there are several equivalent public keys that can be computed. This can lead to [vulnerabilities](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7748#section-7), so it's [recommended](https://doc.libsodium.org/advanced/scalar_multiplication#usage) to hash/KDF the shared secret concatenated with both public keys. That's what the [newer](https://doc.libsodium.org/key_exchange) key exchange API does, but I'm guessing you don't have access to that.

> The sodium port that I'm using is quite limited and does not offer a
> kdf.

This is a problem. If it supports keyed hashing, you can [construct](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48136/blake2b-as-a-kdf) a KDF, but it sounds like you should just switch to a better libsodium binding if possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I fully agree that there is no way around a KDF for what I need. I've skipped a few things in my question, like the fact that the public key exchange has already happened and I was looking for a "less complex" way to have a new (symmetric) encryption key for every message, to ensure perfect secrecy. I need to fill my knowledge gaps and probably write my own set of bindings for libsodium.

Comment: Gotcha. Writing your own binding would be a good way to learn about libsodium, but I'd only publicly publish it if you're happy to maintain it in the future. A lot of bindings end up being unmaintained, which gets a bit messy.